# Interesting Problem on Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors 2

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find Eigen Vectors for this matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & \alpha \\
       0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}$

$\alpha \neq 0$

I tried but couldn't understand how to proceed.

Comment: How about first computing the deterimant of $A-\lambda I$, that's the standard way.

Comment: I am very tempted to only use the definition of eigenvector/eigenvalue here. Let $v=(x,y,z)$ such that $A(x,y,z)^t=\lambda(x,y,z)$. Then we have $A(x,y,z)^t=(\alpha z,0,0)$. Thus $Av=\lambda v$ if and only if $v$ is the zero vector (if $\lambda\neq0$). Does this tell anything to you?

Comment: Perhaps not really so interesting ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints.

a. Observe that the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^3$. Thus the only eigenvalue is 0, and it is triple.

b. Next, observe that the matix is non-diagonalizable. Thus there are at most two (linearly independent) eigenvextors.

c. Try $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: I tried and coming up with you ans. But options are 
$(a)[0,0,\alpha]$
$(b)[\alpha,0,0]$
$(c)[0,0,1]$
$(d)[0,\alpha,0]$

Comment: how (d) can be a Eigenvalue. Eigenvalue has to be scalar not vector.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $A$ this matrix, then 
$$\det(A-\lambda I) = -\lambda^3 = 0 \iff \lambda = 0$$
So the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$. Now, to find the eigenvectors of $A$, you can have a look at a basis of $\ker(A)$.

Comment: I tried and coming up with [1,0,0] and [0,1,0]. But options are (a)[0,0,α] (b)[α,0,0] (c)[0,0,1] (d)[0,α,0]

Comment: @Atinesh This is correct ([1,0,0],[0,1,0]) :)